# VBA to add missing numbers in a column and add a zero in next to it in column B

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone write a code for the following task.

I have a series of numbers in column A and an associated value in column B.

e.g

```
A B

1 144
2 33
5 4
6 56
8 1
```

I need to run a macro that add in the missing consecutive numbers in column A and adds an associated zero value in column b.

e.g

```
1 144
2 33
3 0
4 0
5 4
6 56
7 0
8 1
```

can anyone help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a site that helps you with existing code, so you are expected to show what you have tried so far.  Also, because your example isn't actually in columns, it's rather hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you can present the information on a different sheet, you don't need vba.

On the 2nd sheet, put your numbers in column A, using autofill to get the progression, or use `=A1+1` as a formula to create the progression.

in column B, use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5000,2,FALSE),0)` to find the number, or to put `0` if no number is found

(use `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE))` if your version of excel does not support ISERORR)

Comment: Unfortunately the information can not be presented on a different page. I may need to use a VBA. Any ideas?